# Using Toad with 64bit Oracle Client and Windows 7 64bit Operating System

Tags: toad, oracleclient

After downloading the latest version of Toad for Windows 7 64bit, I am struggling to get it to connect to the database using the existing full Oracle Client that is already on the desktop. The Oracle Client that is there is a 64bit version and is version 12c. When running Toad it says that there is no Oracle Client installed. All of the environment variables have been set up to point to the Oracle Client

I note from the attached link that when using Toad in a 64bit os that you have to use a 32bit client? Is this still the case? If not how do I get it to use the Oracle Client? I cannot use another version because of the application that is using it needs that version.
http://www.quest.com/toad-development-suite-for-oracle/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is been a year, but this never gets old, thanks for the obfuscation created.

Bumped in this issue several times.

Modern versions of Toad for Oracle may not work with the "Instant Client". I had success with early versions of Toad (2012) with the Instant client. You want the full client, which is not easy to find, at the time of the writing you cannot (to my knowledge) browse to it beginning at "oracle.com".  Here is the link you want:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html

In there, find the Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit), yes, 32 bit (on our 64bit machine with Windows 7-64bit even).

The oracle full client zip-file is shy of 700Mb, and will allow you to also include more goodies, like SQLPlus, and other tools (imp,impdp,exp, expdp, etc), in addition to the connectivity sought.

You may need to sign-in ( an oracle account ) to get to that file.